jwilder/nginx-proxy .net 8.0 502 gateway error
I am running the following (simplified) for several sites. net7site is using .net 7 on port 80 and 443. But in .net core 8 it uses 8080 and 8081. net7site works fine but I get a 502 bad gateway on net8site. What is the easiest way I can resolve this? Thanks in advance.
docker stop nginx-proxy
docker rm nginx-proxy
docker run --detach \
    --name nginx-proxy \
    --publish 80:80 \
    --publish 443:443 \
    --volume certs:/etc/nginx/certs \
    --volume vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d \
    --volume html:/usr/share/nginx/html \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
    nginxproxy/nginx-proxy:1.6-alpine

docker stop nginx-proxy-acme
docker rm nginx-proxy-acme
docker run --detach \
    --name nginx-proxy-acme \
    --volumes-from nginx-proxy \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    --volume acme:/etc/acme.sh \
    --env "DEFAULT_EMAIL=alibaba@alibaba.com" \
    nginxproxy/acme-companion:2.4

docker stop net7site
docker rm net7site
docker run --detach \
    --name net7site \
    --env VIRTUAL_HOST=net7site.com,www.net7site.com \
    --env LETSENCRYPT_HOST=net7site.com,www.net7site.com \
    --expose 80 \
    --expose 443 \
    net7site

docker stop net8site
docker rm net8site
docker run --detach \
    --name net8site \
    --env VIRTUAL_HOST=net8site.com,www.net8site.com \
    --env LETSENCRYPT_HOST=net8site.com,www.net8site.com \
    --expose 80 \
    --expose 443 \
    net8site


I was able to solve this by changing net8site to the following:
docker stop net8site
docker rm net8site
docker run --detach \
    --name net8site \
    --env VIRTUAL_HOST=net8site.com,www.net8site.com \
    --env LETSENCRYPT_HOST=net8site.com,www.net8site.com \
    --env VIRTUAL_PORT=8080 \
    --expose 8080 \
    --expose 8081 \
    net8site

